# finding the slope of a 3 dimensional curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives, curves

> The plane $y = −2$ intersects the surface
>
> $$ z = x^3 − y \sin(x + y) $$
>
> in a curve.
>
> What is the slope of the tangent line to this intersection curve at
>   the point $(2, −2, 8)$?

I've tried substituting in $y = -2$ and then finding the derivative of that but I don't think it's right but I'm not too sure what else to do.

Comment: What you did is correct, substitute $y=-2$ since that it where the surface will intersect the plane. Then evaluate the derivative at the x and z coordinate provided.

Comment: Sorry @TonyS.F. I don't really understand what you mean by the second part? I differentiate with respect to x then z and then do I substitute in the x and z co-ordinates given?

Comment: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52062.html

Answer (score 1):

\begin{gather}
z=x^3-y\sin(x+y)\\
z=x^3+2\sin(x-2)\\
\frac{dz}{dx}=3x^2+2\cos(x-2)=14
\end{gather}